# J2ME Audio Streaming

Tags: java-me, audio-streaming, rtp

I am new for audio streaming with RTP. I receive RTP packets from a server.Those RTP packets carry Audio files. How I can receive those rtp packets, read and play using the server port which rtp packets come and its rtcp ports and, our rtp packet receiving port and rtcp port? In [JainSip](http://java.net/projects/jsip/) this can be done with SessionAddress. Please let me know any code sample or any source where I can solve my problem.
I do not use RTSP,and want to handle RTP. I read [this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/08/22/experiments-in-streaming-java-me.html) but it is about rtsp, I tried with it, but I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: actually, your question is not clear. Please organize it and highlight the tagline of the question. Then you will obviously get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I want to receive RTP packets which come from a server. Those RTP packets have audio files. There are many samples how to use RTSP and play audio files. I want to receive rtp packets (may be with a socket connection...) and get audio files inside the rtp packets. I m sorry if the question is not clear. If still it is not clear, let me know which point is not clear. I ll explain more. Thanks

Comment: So, there are two parts of your question.
1. How to receive rtp packets with soicket connection?
2. How to get audio files inside the rtp packets?

Comment: Yes absolutely. But the way of getting rtp packets may differ.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/08/22/experiments-in-streaming-java-me.html) is an example of RTP sending and receiving using J2ME.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. Your example had already been tried ealier and not succeeded.. More things appear in SE cannot be done in J2ME.

Comment: Thanks. I have already added that link also in my question(Last 2 line link "this article"). There, it is about with RTSP not direct RTP. :(

Comment: Actually you didn't mentioned what your problem is. The question was clumsy so I didn't checkout the urls. But when I got the comment. I gave you solution based on that. Thanks.